# Weka: Train and test set are not compatible

Tags: weka

I'm trying to classify some web posts using weka and naive bayes classifier.

First I manually classified many posts (about 100 negative and 100 positive) and I created an .arff file with this form:

```
@relation classtest
@attribute 'post' string
@attribute 'class' {positive,negative}
@data
'RT @burnreporter: Google has now indexed over 30 trillion URLs. Wow. #LeWeb',positive
'A special one for me  Soundcloud at #LeWeb ',positive
'RT @dianaurban: Lost Internet for 1/2 hour at a conference called #LeWeb. Ironic, yes?',negative
   .
   .
   .
```

Then I open *Weka Explorer* loading that file and applying the `StringToWordVector` filter to split the posts in single word attributes.

Then, after doing the same with my dataset, selecting (in classify tab of weka) `naive bayes` classifier and choosing select test set, it returns `Train and test set are not compatible`. What can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the ordering of the attributes is different in train and test sets.

You can use batch filtering as described in http://weka.wikispaces.com/Batch+filtering

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72715345/accuracy-degrade-with-highly-skewed-data-after-handling-imbalance-problem/72722276?noredirect=1#comment128454918_72722276 here

Answer (score 0):

I used batch filter but still have problem. Here is what I did:

java -cp /usr/share/java/weka.jar weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToNominal -R last -b -i trainData.arff -o trainDataProcessed.csv.arff -r testData.arff -s testDataProcessed.csv.arff

I then get the error below:

Input file formats differ.

Later.I figured out two ways to make the trained model working on supplied test set.

Method 1. 
Use knowledge flow. For example something like below: CSVLoader(for train set) -> classAssigner -> TrainingSetMaker -->(classifier of your choice) -> ClassfierPerformanceEvaluator - TextViewer. CSVLoader(for test set) -> classAssigner -> TestgSetMaker -->(the same classifier instance above) -> PredictionAppender -> CSVSaver. Then load the data from the CSVLoader or arffLoder for the training set. The model will be trained. After that load data from the loader for the test set. It will evaluate the model(classifier, for example) on the supplied test set and you can see the result from the textviewer (connected to the ClassifierPerformanceEvaluator) and get the saved result from the CSVSaver or arffSaver connected to the PredictionAppender.An additional column, the "classfied as" will be added to the output file. In my case, I used "?" for the class column in the supplied test set if the class labels are not available.

Method 2. 
Combine the Training and Test set into one file. Then the exact same filter can be applied to both training and test set. Then you can separate training set and test set by applying instance filter. Since I use "?" as class label in the test set. It is not visible in the instance filter indices. Hence just select those indices that you can see in the attribute values to be removed when apply the instance filter. You will get the test data left only. Save it and load it in supply test set at the classifier page.This time it will work. I guess it is the class attribute that causes the NOT compatible train and test set issue. As many classfier requires nominal class attribute. The value of which is converted to the index to available values of the class attribute according to http://weka.wikispaces.com/Why+do+I+get+the+error+message+%27training+and+test+set+are+not+compatible%27%3F